# How to have an anchored view inside a ScrollView?

Tags: android, xml, android-viewpager, scrollview, android-coordinatorlayout

everyone. I'm doing an android app and I'm trying to replicate some of the facebook messenger behaviors. My activity has a coordinatorlayout, inside a tableyout and a viewpager. It's working fine but in a fragment I have a recyclerview inside a nestedscrollerview. Specifically some views, a textview then the recyclerview, I'd like that when scrolling down when it reaches the text above the reyclerview, this text stays anchored in the top and it never gets hidden by the nestedscrollview. Just like the facebook messenger app, like this:
[facebook1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ltcHm.png)
[facebook2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3KyVs.png)

I thought about having a hidden textview outside of the nestedscrollview that becomes visible when the scrollview reaches the other textview, so it looks anchored but I wanted to know if there is a better way of doing this. Thank you.

Here's a simplified version of the code:
Activity's layout:

```xml
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/tool_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        layout="@layout/tool_bar"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:tabMode="fixed"
        app:tabGravity="fill"/>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/viewpager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"  />
```

Fragment Layout:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
    android:background="@color/background">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_margin="25dp">

        <TextView ..../>

        <TextView ..../>

        <!-- I need this textview to be anchored when it's reached by the scrollview -->
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/anchored_textView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:divider="@android:color/darker_gray"
            android:dividerHeight="0.2dp"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Comment: try removing nested scroll from fragment, it should do the trick

Comment: I tried but the scrolling stops working :(